# hosting videos on a subcategory with second host

Tags: dns, cpanel, host

I have a domain (example.com) and two hosts:
1- my primary host for hosting my website
2- my secondary host (a download host) for my videos

I want to self-host my videos on my website, but I don't want to host videos on a subdomain (videos.example.com) and I want to host my videos on a subdirectory.

How can I connect my second host as a subdirectory of my primary host in C-Panl?

Thanks in advance